# "It goes up in your nails"?

Tags: phrase-request

I was describing it to my friend that I bend my finger when I scoop a cream so that it won't get between my nail and finger.

How would you say this clearly?

Can I say it goes up in your nails?

Or should I say it goes up in my nails since I'm talking about myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your phrasings are fine, and I would have no problem understanding your meaning.

That said, I might use the preposition *under* to describe this:

> I bend my fingers so that no ice cream gets under my fingernails.

In AmE at least, you might also hear the dual prepositions *up under*:

> Bend your fingers so that no ice cream goes up under your fingernails.

(For example, from a 2014 book: *She was on her hands and knees that morning, the sun breaking through the clouds, dirt up under her nails, and feeling good spreading the mulch around the little plants*.)

---

A few other notes:

1. You can use a number of verbs, like: *goes under, gets under,* or even *ends up under*.
2. You can use *nails* or *fingernails* interchangeably in a sentence like this: *...goes up under your nails*.
3. Other possible prepositions include *underneath* or *beneath*. [Interesting ngram here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+her+fingernails%2Cunderneath+her+fingernails%2Cbeneath+her+fingernails&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).
4. As for the personal pronouns, that depends on the subject of the sentence. As my two example sentences illustrated, the pronouns should match the subject of the sentence:

   - *I bend my fingers, so no ice cream can get under my nails.*
   - *We bend our fingers, so no ice cream will get under our nails.*